# Please help me out in converting the below sql query to lambda Expression

Tags: sql, linq, lambda, expression

SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
R1.RSLTS_CONFIG_AGE_ID
, SUM(R1.PROV_AGE_GNDR_CNT) AS Prov_FeMaleCount
, SUM( R2.PROV_AGE_GNDR_CNT) AS Prov_Male_Count 
FROM RESULTS_AGE_GENDER R1 
INNER JOIN RESULTS_AGE_GENDER R2 ON R1.RSLTS_CONFIG_AGE_ID=R2.RSLTS_CONFIG_AGE_ID
WHERE  R1.RSLTS_CONFIG_GNDR_ID=13  
AND R2.RSLTS_CONFIG_GNDR_ID=14 
GROUP BY R1.RSLTS_CONFIG_AGE_ID
```

Comment: If you need a developer to do a job, hire one. If you need help to get *your* job done, show some effort.

Answer (score -1):

Exact the same query in Linq extension method syntax.

```
var res = context.RESULTS_AGE_GENDER
   .Join(context.RESULTS_AGE_GENDER
      , r1 => r1.RSLTS_CONFIG_AGE_ID
      , r2 => r2.RSLTS_CONFIG_AGE_ID
      (r1, r2) => r1r2)
   .Where(x => x.r1.RSLTS_CONFIG_GNDR_ID == 13
      && x.r1.RSLTS_CONFIG_GNDR_ID == 14)
   .GroupBy(x => x.r1.RSLTS_CONFIG_AGE_ID)
   .Select(x => new 
   {
      RSLTS_CONFIG_AGE_ID = x.Key,
      Prov_FeMaleCount = x.Sum(y => y.r1.PROV_AGE_GNDR_CNT),
      Prov_Male_Count = x.Sum(y => y.r2.PROV_AGE_GNDR_CNT)
   });
```